# Trouble with device debugging in Xcode10.3 "iPhone has denied the launch request. Internal launch error: process launch failed: Unspecified"

Tags: swift, xcode, swift4

When real device debugging is running, the following trouble happens.

```
Could not launch “MY-APP-NAME” iPhone has denied the launch request.
Internal launch error: process launch failed: Unspecified
```

[error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vXBxh.png)

- Using Xcode 10.3 and Firebase Messaging Cloud.
- After changing provisioning profile and bundle ID, this occurs.
- This uses **one year membership account** and **Provisioning Profile for Development**.
- When using simulator, the problem doesn’t occur.
- Though I changed: `Product > Scheme > Edit Scheme > Run > Executable to Ask On Launch`, this didn’t work.
- Unchecking `Product > Scheme > Edit Scheme > Run > Debug executable` didn’t work as well.
- `rm -r ~/Library/MobileDevice/Provisioning\ Profiles/`. didn’t work.
- `rm -r ~/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/`. didn’t work for me as well.
- Because it seems to be a issue of Provision Profile, I tried to fix. However, I couldn’t reach a solution.
- When it comes to another new project, the same error has occurred.
- The issue also occurred with another device.
- What displays in console is below:

  - `The process failed to exec`
  - `Unable to bootstrap process with bundleID MY-APP-NAME`
  - `Unable to get valid task name port right for pid 635`
  - `The request was denied by service delegate (SBMainWorkspace) for reason: Unspecified.`

```
Bootstrap failed with error: <NSError: 0x280617810; domain:
BKSProcessErrorDomain; code: 1 (bootstrap-failed); reason: "Failed to start job">
Bootstrapping failed for <FBApplicationProcess: 0x16465a240;
MY-APP-NAME; pid: -1> with error: Error Domain=BKSProcessErrorDomain Code=1 "Unable to bootstrap process with bundleID MY-APP-BUNDLE-ID” UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Unable to bootstrap process with bundleID MY-APP-NAME, BKSProcessExitReason=0, NSLocalizedFailureReason=Failed to start job, NSUnderlyingError=0x28061cb40 {Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=3 "No such process" UserInfo={NSLocalizedFailureReason=The process failed to exec, NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=Consult /var/log/com.apple.xpc.launchd/launchd.log for more information, 
NSLocalizedDescription=Unable to get valid task name port right for pid 635}}, BSErrorCodeDescription=bootstrap-failed}
FBSSystemService][0x1555] Error handling open request for MY-APP-NAME: <NSError: 0x281674420; domain: FBSOpenApplicationServiceErrorDomain; code: 1 (RequestDenied); reason: "The request was denied by service delegate (SBMainWorkspace) for reason: Unspecified."> {
description = "The request to open "MY-APP-NAME" failed.";
failureReason = "The request was denied by service delegate (SBMainWorkspace) for reason: Unspecified.";
userInfo = {
    FBSOpenApplicationRequestID = <__NSCFNumber: 0xa56f4bb69cbc0302>;
}
underlyingError = <NSError: 0x281674450; domain: FBSOpenApplicationErrorDomain; code: 1 (Unspecified)> {
    description = "The operation couldn’t be completed.
    (FBSOpenApplicationErrorDomain error 1.)";
  };
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved this issue by deleting all Xcode-related certification. I deleted all Xcode-related file with the intention of clear everything.

1. Open `Keychain Access`
2. Delete `Apple Worldwide Developer Relations Certification Authority`
3. Delete `iPhone Developer: NAME (*****)`
4. Delete `iOS Developer: NAME (NAME)`
5. Search `Xcode` in Keychain Access, and delete all items which can see (I remember this ↓)

   1. `Xcode-Token`
   2. `Xcode-AlternateDSID`
6. Search `iOS` in Keychain Access, and delete all items which can see
7. Search `Developer` in Keychain Access, and delete all items which can see

Answer (score 1):

If you set the team as ***Personal Team*** under **the Signing & Capabilities** tab and you didn't see any error there. so just one thing left.

1. go to your device Settings.
2. navigate to the General.
3. go to Device Management.
4. trust the row specified under the Developer App.

Answer (score 0):

I miss some infos, anyway...

1) Xcode shows "denied" if you have not unlocked device.
2) why "MY-APP-NAME" ? did You set app name?
3) Are You using plain Swift code or some kind of framework?
4) Have you purchased a dev account? Have You made all the stuff with certiifcates/provisioning profile?

Anyway I suggest to create a plain, vanilla project form XCode, without writing anything.
Adding your dev profile, it should work.

Comment: Thank you for commenting.1) If I unlock the device, this didn’t solve 2) Sorry, this should alternate with bundleID. 3) I’m using framework with cocoapods. 4) My account has changed to purchase account, and this may have been the cause.

Comment: pls fix app name, MUST match app on App store.

Comment: It wasn't fixed, even if I create a new project...
Can you think of anything that might have caused this?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that Debug isn't set to use a Distribution profile - it should be set to Development

Answer (score 0):

Sometime Apple has upgrade the Developer Relations Intermediate Certificate. It may not update in keychain.

1. Delete all old certificate
2. Get the latest cert [here](https://www.apple.com/certificateauthority/AppleWWDRCAG3.cer)  and install

Reference : https://developer.apple.com/support/expiration/